# Does the word "findability" exist in English?

Tags: suffixes

There are at least three books with the word *findability* in their title; all of them to be found on Amazon. According to ODE I own, *findability* does not exist.

Is it a new word? If so, then is it allowed to transform any randomly chosen adjective ending in -able into the noun ending in -ability?

Comment: To my mind, any adjective ending in *-able, -ible* can be made into a noun ending in *-ability, -ibility*.

Comment: I think in this age of internet usage, information architecture allows for *findibility*.

Comment: *Findability* is perfectly acceptable among user interface designers, and was coined because *searchability* is a different concept in web communications. If your definition of *exists* is whether or not you can find a corresponding definition in the OED, you'll find a great many words in everyday use by millions of people don't "exist."

Comment: I'm curious: where you've seen this word used, how does the usage differ from "discoverability"?

Comment: @ChrisBergin- I'd suggest that *findability* can refer to the ability to locate something previously known to the finder while *discoverability* seems only to refer to the ability to become aware of the existence of something.

Comment: This is standard reference: ["Findability"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Findability).

Answer (score 4):

Anything is a word if people use it.  English does not have an authority on what is or isn't a "real" word.  Since "findability" does have attestation, it is a word.

This is totally separate from whether it's a *good* word, of course.  But that usually depends on the context in which you plan to use it.

Answer (score 1):

In 2013, I attended a meeting with my work group. One announcement my boss made was, more or less: *OK guys, findability. If you're gonna be away from your desk for more than a half-hour, put a sticky  note on your door.*

Comment: I'll take this as a definitive demonstration of things that one *can* say, but probably shouldn't. Cheers!